# Content Editable DIV is not taking any space randomly in Firefox and IE

Tags: firefox, contenteditable

Content Editable DIV is not taking any space randomly in Firefox and IE. Sometimes it works fine, but often apparently starts ignoring the white-space key.

Leaving the window open for a while when it works fine worsens it further - it starts showing the same problem - ignoring the white key space.

The problem is only with typing. When paste text having spaces, it is rendered properly, even if I was not able to key in White Spaces.

It works consistently fine in Google Chrome.

I'm using "white-space: pre", but also tried with "white-space: pre-wrap". No help.

I have recent version of Firefox (40.0).

Comment: I have observed that "keydown" event has captured the "SPACE" key, but somehow it is not being appended to the existing string in the content editable.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for your contenteditable (cs, js, html)?